# Find what python Module/class is the most memory hungry

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks, gstreamer, heap-memory

I have a relatively big project with 8 active threads that communicate with the pykka actor module, and I use gstreamer library.

My project now uses too much memory, and I need to find what module is so memory hungry

```
743     1   root     S     340m   141.7   0  26.3  {run} /usr/bin/python
21090   757 root     R     3024  1.2      0  0.3   top
```

I have seen that memory occupation doesn't decrease if I run the modules separately, so I think that is mostly an import problem.
I'm using python 2.7.11

1. If I import a module with `import module` or I import only the function that I need `from module import a, b` would the memory occupation decrease?
2. Does defining more classes/functions increase python memory occupation?
   What about subclassing or having more separate files instead of one with more classes in it?
3. With heapy I have managed to print some heap occupation value
   but I cannot print from where it is used

I see that I have 100MB of strings... 100MB? How is that possible?

```
from guppy import hpy
hp = hpy()
h = hp.heap()

print(h)
print(h.byrcs)
print(h.bytype)
print(h.bymodule)
print(h.byclass)
```

‌
Output:

```
fresa@fresa:/nfs_icore/player$ PYTHONPATH=.:../base python run
INFO     [(__init__.py:114)] base.config | Loading config from builtin defaults
INFO     [(__init__.py:158)] base.config | Loading config from /home/fresa/.config//player.conf
INFO     [(__init__.py:139)] base.config | Loading config from command line options
INFO     [(__init__.py:114)] base.config | Loading config from builtin defaults
INFO     [(__init__.py:139)] base.config | Loading config from command line options
Partition of a set of 25973 objects. Total size = 3541320 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0  12613  49  1057496  30   1057496  30 str
     1   5877  23   511480  14   1568976  44 tuple
     2    117   0   306168   9   1875144  53 dict of module
     3    192   1   281472   8   2156616  61 dict (no owner)
     4    281   1   253360   7   2409976  68 type
     5   1566   6   200448   6   2610424  74 types.CodeType
     6   1528   6   183360   5   2793784  79 function
     7    209   1   148760   4   2942544  83 dict of type
     8    286   1   108632   3   3051176  86 unicode
     9    285   1    44456   1   3095632  87 list
<123 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
_
._Partition of a set of 25973 objects. Total size = 3541320 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Referrers by Kind (class / dict of class)
     0   9024  35   817096  23    817096  23 types.CodeType
     1   1660   6   329872   9   1146968  32 dict of module
     2    912   4   278856   8   1425824  40 type
     3   1883   7   242272   7   1668096  47 function
     4    664   3   225232   6   1893328  53 function, tuple
     5     77   0   214328   6   2107656  60 function, module
     6   2914  11   179080   5   2286736  65 tuple
     7   1214   5   163960   5   2450696  69 dict of type
     8   2491  10   163168   5   2613864  74 dict (no owner)
     9    418   2    96800   3   2710664  77 dict of module, tuple
<297 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
Partition of a set of 25973 objects. Total size = 3541320 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Type
     0  12613  49  1057496  30   1057496  30 str
     1    781   3   874936  25   1932432  55 dict
     2   5877  23   511480  14   2443912  69 tuple
     3    281   1   253360   7   2697272  76 type
     4   1566   6   200448   6   2897720  82 types.CodeType
     5   1528   6   183360   5   3081080  87 function
     6    286   1   108632   3   3189712  90 unicode
     7    285   1    44456   1   3234168  91 list
     8    474   2    41712   1   3275880  93 __builtin__.weakref
     9     37   0    37576   1   3313456  94 __builtin__.StgDict
<83 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
Partition of a set of 25973 objects. Total size = 3541320 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Module
     0  25856 100  3534768 100   3534768 100 ~module
     1      1   0       56   0   3534824 100 ConfigParser
     2      1   0       56   0   3534880 100 Queue
     3      1   0       56   0   3534936 100 SocketServer
     4      1   0       56   0   3534992 100 _ctypes
     5      1   0       56   0   3535048 100 _dbus_bindings
     6      1   0       56   0   3535104 100 _dbus_glib_bindings
     7      1   0       56   0   3535160 100 _hashlib
     8      1   0       56   0   3535216 100 _io
     9      1   0       56   0   3535272 100 _random
<108 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
Partition of a set of 25973 objects. Total size = 3541320 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Class
     0  12613  49  1057496  30   1057496  30 str
     1    781   3   874936  25   1932432  55 dict
     2   5877  23   511480  14   2443912  69 tuple
     3    281   1   253360   7   2697272  76 type
     4   1566   6   200448   6   2897720  82 types.CodeType
     5   1528   6   183360   5   3081080  87 function
     6    286   1   108632   3   3189712  90 unicode
     7    285   1    44456   1   3234168  91 list
     8    474   2    41712   1   3275880  93 __builtin__.weakref
     9     37   0    37576   1   3313456  94 __builtin__.StgDict
<83 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
```

Comment: The 100MB strings could come from lots of working with strings, as Python always creates copies.

Comment: what can I do to identify where are??

Comment: Wherever you are using `+` to concatenate strings for example